# asp.net back button not posting back because of validation errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

I have a asp.net wizard with back, next, cancel buttons. I have causes validation set to true on the next, false on the back and cancel buttons. This was working fine until the product owner wanted to have block ui enabled on the back button, since posts sometimes were slow. As usual, I did this:

```
$("[id$=_myBackButton]").click(function () {
    // call func to enable block ui.
    enableBlockUI();

    return true;
});
```

This would work fine until the following occurred. If, for example, on the second step, the user clicks the next button without filling out all required text boxes, client side validation would occur. Now, if user wishes to go to the previous step and presses the back button, block ui is enabled and a post back is not fired. Because I added a JQuery click event and perhaps I overrode the causesvalidation.

So, how can I get the back button to work and proceed to the previous step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a click event to _myBackButton try a class name.  So add CssClass="_myBackButton" (if an ASP.NET control) and then change your jQuery to:

```
$("._myBackButton").click(function () {
    // call func to enable block ui.
    enableBlockUI();
});
```